# Android: What part of Image is visible in ImageView

Tags: android, image, imageview

Ok,  I know there must be a simple solution to this, but maybe I am just overtired because I'm just not finding it.

I have an imageview with am image that is larger than its physical size, I have implimented that the user can scroll around the image just fine, but I am having a devil of a time finding out what part of the image is actually being displayed.

IE what is the X,Y coordinate in the image that is currently at 0,0 in the visible space.

I know this has to be mind numbingly simple, but I am just not finding the right method or variable to reference for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your ScrollViews, you can get the scrollX and scrollY.  You should be able to use that.

Comment: Sort of.. This gives me scroll relative to how the image was originally displayed.. IE if scrollType was set to center the getScrollX and getScrollY will show where I am relative to that starting point.. but does not give me the X,Y relative to the image itself that is displayed.  I suppose I can get rid of the scrollType and programatically move to the center to get what I need, but that seems kludgy.. Is there no method that says "here is the X,Y of the drawable that is currently displayed in the imageview?